# Java - Sending byte object over socket

Tags: java, object, byte, objectoutputstream

I'm using an ObjectOutputStream over my socket because I created a new class that needs to be transported between the client and the server.
I also created a unique thread that sends one byte every one second over the stream to the server in order to inspect the connection continuously and check that its alive.

```
byte b=1;
oos.writeObject(b);
```

I use "byte" because it is the smallest object that I can send (right?) so that the server will not read longer objects.

My question is if the server reads one byte object (size of byte) or an 8 byte object (the size of an object)
?

Comment: A byte is *not* the smallest object you can send; a bit is.  A byte consists of 8 bits.  Booleans are equivalent to bytes.  Using `writeObject` will result in the class, class signature, and serializable fields to be written to the stream as well, so the size will vary; I recommend testing that out on your own for the case of a Byte object.

Comment: Do you mean an object size is 8 byte?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot send/receive one bit in Java. The best thing you can do is pack 8 separate bits into a byte and send that one byte and unpack the bits on the other side, which can be used to send up to 8 true/false (1/0) values in one byte instead of 8 bytes of values 1 or 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably neither.  First, a `byte` is autoboxed into a `Byte`.  Then the `Byte` is serialized to your output stream.  It probably takes quite a bit more than 8 bytes to send.  I don't know the spec exactly, but it probably sends the class name `java.lang.Byte` and the byte itself, plus probably a few more control bytes.

An easy way to tell - serialize your byte to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, flush your `ObjectOutputStream`, then see how many bytes your `ByteArrayOutputStream` ends up with.

Comment: `writeObject` sends the class name, class signature, the object's serializable values, and stream headers.  You are correct on saying "neither", so +1.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use an ObjectOutputStream, it really doesn't matter which object you send because after the first one is sent, a reference to that object will be sent in the future.  For this reason I suggest you send a specific enum like.

```
enum Control {
    HEARTBEAT
}
```

You could make the wire format much smaller using DataOutputStream where 1 byte is one byte.  Given the IP packet header is about 20 bytes, it doesn't really matter whether you send 1 byte or 8 bytes as the overhead is much higher than this.